# WebGUI for Ruby crawler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface, web-crawler

I have written a web crawler in pure Ruby, without Rails.
It is command-line only at the moment and I'm looking for a good framework to create a GUI.
I thought about doing it with GTk, but since the crawler will run on a dedicated server, a web-GUI would be much better.

What would be a good framework to make this in?
I know of Rails of course, is it reasonable to use it for that?

The GUI would mainly consist of a monitoring page, where I can see the progress, have a few nice charts and can stop and start the crawler. The actual crawling is done in the existing Ruby app and would run in background.

So, should I use a Rails app with background threads running the crawler or is there a better way?

Comment: Sinatra would be a good choice in such case http://sinatrarb.com

Comment: Rails would work just fine, but may be overkill, depending on the size of your application. You may want to use a front-end framework like Angular or Backbone or something and hit an API built with Sinatra or something else lightweight

Comment: Sinatra seems to be what I'm looking for. Is it possible to make a value change without refreshing the page? E.g. I would like to display a count of the pages crawled that changes as the crawler works without having to refresh the page to see the new number.

Comment: You can use dynamic HTML with Sinatra; Just write the handlers and use something like jQuery in the HTML to talk to Sinatra. I favor Sinatra, HAML and jQuery but YMMV.